# How do one for loop for different arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

I have different popups that are hidden by default and get shown by a click and Javascript magic. So, this results in my beginner Javascript brain in multiple lines of JS code which are looking quite the same.

For all of these popup boxes I'm using the following code:

```js
var paperComButton = document.getElementsByClassName('paperCompanieButton');

for (var i = 0; i < paperComButton.length; i++) {
  paperComButton[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var greyOut = document.getElementById('greyOut');
    var popupWrapper = document.getElementById('popupWrapperFlex');
    var popup = document.getElementById('paperCompanieInfo');

    greyOut.style.zIndex = '5';
    popupWrapper.style.zIndex = '6';
    popup.style.zIndex = '1';
    greyOut.style.opacity = '1';
    popupWrapper.style.opacity = '1';
    popup.style.opacity = '1';
  });
}
```

The next one is looking mostly the same

```js
var pdfPreviewButton = document.getElementsByClassName('pdfPreviewButton');

for (var i = 0; i < pdfPreviewButton.length; i++) {
  pdfPreviewButton[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var greyOut = document.getElementById('greyOut');
    var popupWrapper = document.getElementById('popupWrapperFlex');
    var popup = document.getElementById('paperJobPdf');

    greyOut.style.zIndex = '5';
    popupWrapper.style.zIndex = '6';
    popup.style.zIndex = '1';
    greyOut.style.opacity = '1';
    popupWrapper.style.opacity = '1';
    popup.style.opacity = '1';
  });
}
```

The problem is that I have not just this two popups, so the JS code get quite big.

My question: is there any possibility to merge these code lines to a more universal one?
Hope so there is a simple way to do, so I can understand what is going on in my beginner mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why Javascript has functions. They allow you to take behavior that is the same, or almost the same, and package it into a reusable container. In your example, everything is identical except the class name of the buttons and the document ID. So you can create a function that takes these two things as arguments and then does the repetitive code. For example if you define a function like:

```
function setPopup(className, documentID) {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

        var greyOut = document.getElementById('greyOut');
        var popupWrapper = document.getElementById('popupWrapperFlex');
        var popup = document.getElementById(documentID);

        greyOut.style.zIndex = '5';
        popupWrapper.style.zIndex = '6';
        popup.style.zIndex = '1';
        greyOut.style.opacity = '1';
        popupWrapper.style.opacity = '1';
        popup.style.opacity = '1';
        });
    }   
}
```

You can then use your new function without repeating all the same code over and over, by simply calling it with new arguments:

```
setPopup('paperCompanieButton', 'paperCompanieInfo')
setPopup('pdfPreviewButton', 'paperJobPdf')
```

as many times as you want.

Comment: Thank you a lot! That will simplify my code imense, my understanding of javascript too! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor this code like this:

```
function setupButtonsPopups(buttonClassName, popupId) {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName(buttonClassName);
    var popup = document.getElementById(popupId);
    var greyOut = document.getElementById('greyOut');
    var popupWrapper = document.getElementById('popupWrapperFlex');

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            greyOut.style.zIndex = '5';
            popupWrapper.style.zIndex = '6';
            popup.style.zIndex = '1';
            greyOut.style.opacity = '1';
            popupWrapper.style.opacity = '1';
            popup.style.opacity = '1';
        });
    }
}

setupButtonsPopups('paperCompanieButton', 'paperCompanieInfo');
setupButtonsPopups('pdfPreviewButton', 'paperJobPdf');
```

Note, that the only difference between two parts of code are `buttons class name` and `popup id`. So let's make a function, that will take this arguments and encapsulate all other stuff.

Comment: Thank you too, this helped me a lot!